# R connect via proxy in Ubuntu

Tags: r, proxy, rstudio

I had installed RStudio 0.97.168 on Ubuntu 12.04.  When I try to install gstat library I get the below error

```
install.packages("gstat", dependencies=TRUE)

Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open: HTTP status was '407 Proxy Authentication Required'
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open: HTTP status was '407 Proxy Authentication Required'
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository http://software.rc.fas.harvard.edu/mirrors/R/src/contrib
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘gstat’ is not available (for R version 2.14.1)
```

I saw solutions like `--intenet` and `setInternet(TRUE)` which are only applicable for Windows OS.

Please provide help on changes I need to make to get behind my university proxy?

Comment: Take a look at http://techmonks.net/how-to-make-your-linux-applications-use-proxy/

Comment: @Paul, My network proxy settings uses my university proxy. I have no issues with other application. It is very specific to RStudio.

Comment: @subash, What are the "other applications" you refer to and where did you set the proxy for them? This is most likely not specific to RStudio, but to R or programs run at the command line. Do you have success running, say, `wget` or `apt-get upgrade` with your current settings?

Comment: @mrdwab I dont any problem while using ubuntu software centre, package manager or update manger. They work like charm. apt-get upgrade also works fine.

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to use the following in your R session:

```
Sys.setenv(http_proxy="http://user:pass@proxy.dom.com:8080/")
```

(Obviously, replace with your username, password, proxy server, and port.)

It's important that this is done ***before*** you first try to download anything--in other words, done preferably at the start of an R session. From the help page at `?download.file`:

> These environment variables must be set before the download code is first used: they cannot be altered later by calling Sys.setenv.

There are ways to make this change "permanent" too, but that might be inconvenient if you are working on a laptop or working with multiple internet connections, some of which requires access via a proxy server, and some which don't.

Comment: Do you suggest to add the line, before I install any library, as I had done few already?

Comment: @subash, I don't understand: have you been successful installing some packages but not others?

Comment: I meant to say that I had installed libraries by downloading the .tar.gz files and installed it manually as I could not get across the proxy.

Answer (score 3):

You can try.

```
R.home()
find file Renviron.site
And add you proxy server address in R_HOME/etc/Renviron.site
http_proxy=http://<<your proxy server address>>/

This steps help me.
```