# R proxy settings IP and Port

Tags: r, proxy, settings

In my office we are using proxy to get internet.

I have IP and Port numbers.

How can I configure R (in R studio) permanently? to enter from that proxy settings.

Thanks!

Comment: Useful resource: https://github.com/cderv/proxyconfig

Answer (score 0):

This answer helped me: [R connect via proxy in Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13264761/r-connect-via-proxy-in-ubuntu)

I just set the proxy variables in the Renviron file and when starting R they are permananently set!